# ¿Cuándo llega el modo oscuro a Stack Overflow en español?

Tags: discusión, interfaz-de-usuario, modo-oscuro

Estoy tan acostumbrado al modo oscuro que cada vez me molesta más entrar a Stack Overflow en español y que esta opción aún no esté disponible.

¿Alguien sabe cuándo llegará el modo oscuro a Stack Overflow en español o por que aún no está disponible si en la versión en inglés ya está desde hace varios meses?

Comment: Por añadir algo a la respuesta de @glorfindel , hay que tener en cuenta que cada sitio de la red tiene sus particularidades (esquemas de color, logotipos...) por lo que tiene su dificultad y no es simplemente dar a un boton, hay que analizar cada sitio uno a uno.

Comment: Mientras llega, puedes usar algún script o plugin. Por ejemplo: [DarkReader](https://darkreader.org). Entiendo que no es exactamente lo mismo, pero sí que ayuda. Saludos

Comment: Lo mismo me preguntaba. En la noche es la única página que ilumina mi habitación. Por mientras, en la noche, puedes (y deberías) atenuar un poco con el filtro de luz nocturna, Night Color en windows 10, KDE también tiene una función nativa, en otros escritorios el proyecto [Redshift](https://github.com/jonls/redshift) funciona bien. En OSX no se.

Comment: Depende simplemente de los programadores de StackExchange, y no creo que se pueda contribuir de ninguna manera. Mientras tanto, puedes hacer como yo y usar [este script para tampermonkey](https://stackapps.com/questions/8053/stack-exchange-dark-mode)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nada se sabe de momento, pero [estaba en beta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/395949/4751173) y primero se implementará en Meta Stack Overflow. ***Sospecho*** que pueden implementar el modo oscuro en Stack Overflow en español y los otros sitios Stack Overflow internacionales, porque ellos usan el mismo tema; publiqué una pregunta sobre esto en Meta Stack Exchange: [Are there any plans to roll out Dark Mode to non-English Stack Overflow sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/351248/295232)